# mongo + java + too many open files

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I am using mongo-java2.4jar for communicating with the mongo server.
In my webapp i am using `mongo=new Mongo("serverIp","port")` where ever it is required and once the processing is complete, I am closing the mongo connection using `mongo.close()`.

But after some time I am getting following exception :

> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

I think when I close the connection it is not closing the sockets.
Please help me out figuring this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: what platform are you on?  You should look at your open sockets as you use this.  If you're on a unix-ish system, use netstat.  Check out how many connections are open to where and what state they're in.

Comment: On linux you can see the number of open sockets with `netstat -p` on windows there should be something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mongo class transparently does connection pooling and you should generally have only one instance per JVM process. Please look at http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5-pre-/com/mongodb/Mongo.html

If you heavily create instances of this class i think you will acquire too many connections before they can be released. Just create a singleton on app startup for your whole application and place it in the application context. Call close only when your app stops.

Cheers,

Sven

Comment: the link is broken :(